# Laravel Query Sort fields even and odd in that order

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table that I want to fetch records in a certain way. Below is the table.
[image]

I want a query to fetch me all records of a selected vessel code and order them by the product_id and arrange the type in the order [1,2] for each product. Right now, the query I have is this `VesselProductDetails::where('vessel_code',$vessel_code)->orderByDesc('type')->get();` arranges the type in ascending order, but I want it to be 1,2 1,2 in that order

Comment: Ohk, this won't work for me. I need a query that can fetch the data how they're arranged in the picture above.Just in that manner.Im much in particular about the type field. The sequence they appear is exactly how I want my data to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple sorts in your query.

```
VesselProductDetails::where('vessel_code',$vessel_code)
->orderBy('vessel_code', 'asc')
->orderBy('type', 'asc')
->get();
```

Hope this will work for you.